# Stalks of an inverse image sheaf are same as the stalks (using adjoints)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $\pi:X\to Y$ be a continuous map, $\pi(p)=q$. Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a sheaf on $Y$. I want to show that there is a natural isomorphism $\mathcal{G}_q \to (\pi^{-1}\mathcal{G})_p$ by using the adjunction of inverse image and pushforward.

To start, we notice that a stalk is a colimit, which commutes with left adjoints (inverse image here). Hence,$$(\pi^{-1}\mathcal{G})_p=\lim_{p\in U}\pi^{-1}\mathcal{G}(U)=\pi^{-1}\lim_{p\in U}\mathcal{G}(U)=\pi^{-1}(\mathcal{G_p}).$$

I don't know how to make sense of $\pi^{-1}(\mathcal{G_p})$ such that it is isomorphic to $\mathcal{G}_q$. Please feel free to show me other ways (by using adjoints) if my approach doesn't make much sense to you.

Comment: Stalks are inverse limits; the stalk of $\mathcal G$ at $q$ is the inverse image of the sheaf under $\{*\}\to Y$ given by $*\mapsto q$. Now use functoriality of inverse limit.

Comment: Be careful with your commutation of functor with limits. What is true is that, if $F$ commute with colimits, then $\varinjlim F\circ G = F(\varinjlim G)$. So what you wrote is tempting but false and in fact a total non sens : $\pi^{-1}\mathcal{G}(U)$ is in fact $\Gamma(U,\pi^{-1}\mathcal{G})$, so it is absolutely not of the form $\pi^{-1}\circ G$ for some functor $G$. That is why you end up with $\pi^{-1}(\mathcal{G}_p)$ which does not mean anything (what is the $\pi^{-1}$ of an abelian group ?)

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thank you! But can you show me how to use the functoriality of the inverse limit in this problem?

Comment: @Angina: upvoted your very nice answer, but it should say "stalks are inverse images". Tripped me up for a bit...